# Way to get crash reports in legacy project?

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode-organizer

Recently I've got a legacy project to work on. It's the iOS application already published in the AppStore. There is a very specific crash, that depends on local user data. iTunes Connect shows that it keeps arising, but I can't see any crash reports in my Xcode Organizer related to the project. It merely says something like "The product doesn't have crash data", and doesn't show me the Version and build menu.

I went through the App Distribution Guide, and in accordance with the section [Before Viewing Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH21-SW6) I should not delete the archive I uploaded to the iTunes Connect:

> Do not delete archives that you upload to iTunes Connect.

The problem is that these archives are created locally, this project was started by another team, we don't have contacts with anymore, and therefore I'm not able to have corresponding archives for the published application. Is there a way to retrieve crash reports for such a legacy project?

Comment: What about doing a minor app update and wait for a new crash report? Don't think there is another way.

Comment: @OliverM, my conclusion with the archives is just an assumption. I can't belive that it works this way. Does it mean that even if I were in the original team, only one person, who uploaded the build to the AppStore is able to review crash reports?

Comment: Yes it does. (if the one person is the only one to access the dsym files) Think of using an external crash handling tool, like Crashlytics oder Bugsnag. You can automate your build process to upload the dsym's at build time so you don't have to archive these yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I conducted a small research and it seems that there is no way to get or re-symbolicate the crash reports without original archives. It's confirmed by the [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs) of [Soheil Azarpour](https://www.raywenderlich.com/u/canopus):

> **Note**: You must keep both the application binary and the .dSYM file to be able to fully symbolicate crash reports. You should archive these files for every build that you submit to iTunes Connect.
>   The .dSYM and application binary are specifically tied together on a per-build-basis, and subsequent builds, even from the same source files, will not interoperate with files from other builds.